# How to check if a string contains special characters?

Tags: c#, string

I'm using an API, I pass 2 string as parameters.
If I introduce the strings programmatically as:

```
string a = "Madrid, Spain";
```

Eveything is fine, the API response is OK.
But everything changes when I use a textbox to introduce the same "Madrid, Spain".

```
string b = TextBox1.Text;
```

If I use string b to call the API I get a Request_Denied.

Essentially string a and string b has the same content but something must be different.

C# strings are not null terminated, I've tried to check using `String.EndsWith(Enviroment.NewLine)` if it ends with a newline since I was using enter to insert the value. I've tried get the char[] representation of the string to see if I was able to get special characters but seems to have none.

Since string in C# is Unicode and some methods use ASCII like Trim(char[]) I'm not sure how to use them.

My main goal is to be able to see all the characters that are contained in the string as ASCII or Unicode, so I can check what is causing the problem with the API.

Edit: In the end it seems like the problem was with the API but I managed to get the hex value as I asked so I learned something new. Thanks

Comment: What result do you get from `a == b` ?

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: You'll need to know the encoding used for "TextBox1.Text". Since you haven't mentioned your UI technology (Web Forms, MVC, WinForms, WPF, etc.), it's a bit difficult to say with certainty.

Comment: Why would you want to output your string as ASCII? Jeez... just put a breakpoint in your code and debug to see where it differs...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Any property called "Text" ought to be a `System.String`, which is always UTF-16.

Comment: Are you using "ASCII" like [Kleenex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark)? It makes your question confusing because ASCII is a real, distinct thing that isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the hex value of your characters.

```
foreach (char c in "Hello World !")
    Console.WriteLine(((int)c).ToString("X"));
```

Comment: "Characters" is a bit imprecise but yes, that code will show the UTF-16 code unit (`char`) sequence in the string as hexadecimal values.

Comment: What do you mean by imprecise ? If you talk about size, I don't think it's a problem here x) Maybe you were thinking about something else that I don't know about :)

Comment: A sort of middle ground meaning of "character" is an element in a character set. A more formal name for that is codepoint. However, Unicode avoids having a codepoint for every natural combination of letters and zero or more diacritics by having "combining" codepoints. The formal name for a combination is grapheme. Now, an encoding takes a codepoint value and converts it to a stored representation. Each codepoint is encoded in one or multiples of the storage unit, called a code unit. UTF-16 encodes each Unicode codepoint in one or two 16-bit code units. In C#, the datatype is `char`.

Comment: For sure, I will have some lecture to make, it still a bit confure, but I already heard about that. Thanks for your answer I really appreciate :) And for your last question, I guess the answer will depend on the OP's string.